# How can i make a loop that will show '-' mark x time iteration was?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to write a simple code with using a loop, in console that will look like this.

> 01-2--3---4----5-----6------7-------

Ok i've got a answer, code should look like this

```
var input = 7;
var oputPut = "";
var executeLoop = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= input; i++) {
        oputPut += i;
        var count = i;
        while (count > 0) {
            oputPut += '-';
            count--;
        }
    }
}();
console.log(oputPut);
```

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: and what have you tried so far? Could you show your attempt please?

Comment: Hint: [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)...

Comment: might be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: I've tryied many ways but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try it out: '-'.repeat(k);